# message inbox in android

Tags: java, android, xml, inbox

i've been trying to develop an application that displays all your text messages in the old fashioned nokia style, which means you have a listview with the contact that sent you a message, and when you click on that, your message appears in a textview.
So, here is what i did :- I made a messageoutline class

```
package com.one.inbox;

  public class MessageOutline {
private String phone;
private String message;

public MessageOutline(String phone, String message){
    setPhone(phone);
    setMessage(message);

}
public void setPhone(String Phone){
    MessageOutline.this.phone=phone;
}
public void setMessage(String Message){
    MessageOutline.this.message=Message;
}
public String getPhone(){
    return this.phone;
}
public String getMessage(){
    return this.message;
}
    }
```

In the mainactivity i have this arraylist which i use in arrayadater and call setlistadapter by using the arrayadapter object instantiated with the arraylist :-

```
package com.one.inbox;

  import java.util.ArrayList;

  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.app.ListActivity;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

   public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
public static ArrayList<MessageOutline> mList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mList=new ArrayList<MessageOutline>();
    ArrayAdapter<MessageOutline> array=new ArrayAdapter<MessageOutline>(this,                           android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mList);
    setListAdapter(array);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

    }
```

then there is this messagelistener which is a broadcast receiver, in which i add objects to the arraylist

```
package com.one.inbox;

 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.telephony.SmsManager;
 import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
 import android.util.Log;
  import android.widget.Toast;

public class MessageListener extends BroadcastReceiver{
    final SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {

        if (bundle != null) {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                MainActivity.mList.add(new MessageOutline(senderNum,message));
                Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);


               // Show Alert
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, 
                             "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                toast.show();

            } // end for loop
          } // bundle is null

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

    }
}    
}
```

here is my mainactivity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
           android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

</ListView>
```

and here goes the manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.one.inbox"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.one.inbox.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="com.one.inbox.MessageListener">
        <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
 </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


</application>

</manifest>
```

i dont know whats going wrong as the logcat is showing no exceptions, and the activity is not stopping, but nothing is happening in the main screen.

What i want is the mainscree should show a list with contact name or number, and when you click on them, a textview with the message body must open, i havent implemented the onlistitemclick listener yet, coz, i want to solve the first problem as nothing is showing in the screen.

any help would be most humbly appreciated. Thanx.

Comment: And suddenly my r file goes missing.. I did clean and build several times. . No change..

Comment: Solved the problem. .. if someone is in need for how did I.. pls ask.. I wud be helpful as much as possible.